# Framework for distributed enterprise application with stateless services?

Tags: java, scalability, distributed-computing, enterprise

We are developing an enterprise application in a client server mode.

The requirements are:

- the server side: cluster or distributed to scale very well (multiple clients)
- service instances in server are pooled (so that they can be allocated to any of the distributed cluster elements)
- service instances are stateless (i.e. the request from client can be handled by any service instance)

Appreciate if you can suggest a good distributed enterprise software development book as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you could have a look at the Hazelcast Distributed Datagrid.

[Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)

They provide the classic key/value cache but also some nice structures like distributed queues. It provides Distribution for many parts of an Enterprise Solution (Distributed Hibernate 2nd level cache, Session Distribution, Spring Integration). 
The thing that can be interesting for you is the use of the Distributed Executor interface of Hazelcast. So you can execute threads on any node of the cluster.

If this approach is to lightweight for you. You should look into ESB ([Enterprise Service Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus)) and Messaging queues. 
You could start playing around a little with Active MQ paired with Apache Camel. (both open source)

[Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/)

[Active MQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)

Comment: Thanks Esquive for the answer !!

Comment: I hope the tools I recommended can help you. Sadly I don't know a good book about this. The books I know cover enterprise solutions but never deeply the distributed aspect...